# Yii2 each validation rule for url. Returns error if field is empty

Tags: validation, yii2, each, rules

I have a problem with validation some text inputs with the same name.
I validate it with `each` validation rule. Each fields validates with url value.

```
[['links'], 'each', 'rule' => [
    'url', 'defaultScheme' => 'http', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'message' => 'This url isn\'t valid'
]],
```

This is my form input:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'links[]')->textInput(); ?>
```

But if my links inputs are empty I get next message: `This url isn't valid`.
This rule works for single input, but doesn't work for multiple.

Could You advise something?

Comment: You are used `foreach` loop?

Comment: Why  'links[]' and not links...?

Comment: @HirenBhut, no, $this->validate() return error. I can add that it works with 'string' validation and doesn't work with 'url'.

Comment: @scaisEdge, because everyone can add many urls to his contact information. And then I receive an array of links.

Answer (score 1):

By default, an input is considered empty if its value is an empty string, an empty array or a `null`. You may customize the default empty detection logic by configuring the `yii\validators\Validator::isEmpty()` property with a PHP callable. For example,

```
['agree', 'required', 'isEmpty' => function ($value) {
    return empty($value);
}]
```

Note: Most validators do not handle empty inputs if their `yii\validators\Validator::$skipOnEmpty` property takes the default value true. They will simply be skipped during validation if their associated attributes receive empty inputs. Among the core validators, only the **captcha, default, filter, required, and trim** validators will handle empty inputs.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html

Comment: How can I use it in my situation? Array with links isn't empty. Fields are without value. I cannot add sth to my rule with url. There is nothing in Yii2 documentation.

Comment: for more flexible validation you can use you own functions 

   ['links', 'exist', 'allowArray' => true, 'when' => function ($model, $attribute) {
foreach($model->links as $link ){
if(..){ 
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}],

Comment: tanks, but I wanted to use default yii url validation to avoid regular expressions and concatenations with http/https

Comment: Try add another one rule   ['links', 'safe']

Answer (score 1):

It was asked a long time ago, but if anyone ends up on this page like me...

The propper way (at least the way I struggled to find out), on Yii, to create multiple models on the same form is:

```
controller
$links = [];
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
   $links['link'. $i] = new Link();
}
return $this->render('view', ['links' => $links]);

view
foreach($links as $index => $link) {
   echo $form->field($link, '['. $index .']link')->textInput();
}
```

This way you can even use `Model::validateMultiple` and `Model::loadMultiple`.